# Can someone help me to fix this binary tree in Java?

Tags: java

The user must input a key to a node, and pick one of the three order choices. They can press the indicated number to perform an operation. I need this code as soon as possible because finals is coming :(

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class BinaryTree {

public static int choice,listLength;



Node root;

public void addNode(int key, String name) {



    Node newNode = new Node(key, name);



    if (root == null) {

        root = newNode;

    } else {




        Node focusNode = root;



        Node parent;

        while (true) {




            parent = focusNode;




            if (key < focusNode.key) {



                focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;



                if (focusNode == null) {


                    parent.leftChild = newNode;
                    return;
                }

            } else {

                focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;


                if (focusNode == null) {



                    parent.rightChild = newNode;
                    return;

                }

            }

        }
    }

}



public void inOrderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {

    if (focusNode != null) {



        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);



        System.out.println(focusNode);



        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);

    }

}

public void preorderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {

    if (focusNode != null) {

        System.out.println(focusNode);

        preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);
        preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);

    }

}

public void postOrderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {

    if (focusNode != null) {

        postOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);
        postOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);

        System.out.println(focusNode);

    }

}

public Node findNode(int key) {



    Node focusNode = root;



    while (focusNode.key != key) {



        if (key < focusNode.key) {



            focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;

        } else {



            focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;

        }



        if (focusNode == null)
            return null;

    }

    return focusNode;

}

 public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 String x;
 int y;

    BinaryTree theTree = new BinaryTree();





     theTree.inOrderTraverseTree(theTree.root);









do
{
    try
        {
System.out.println("Choose: ");
System.out.println("[1]Insert ");
System.out.println("[2]Delete ");
System.out.println("[3]Display ");
System.out.println("[4]Search");
System.out.println("[5]Exit");
System.out.println("====================");
choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
switch(choice)
{
    case 1 :    System.out.println("INSERT");
                System.out.println("Enter a key: ");
                y = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());


                System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
                x = br.readLine();
                theTree.addNode(y,x);
                System.out.println("Tree: " + theTree.findNode(y));
                break;

    case 2 :    System.out.println("DELETE");
                System.out.println("Enter the node to remove: ");
                x = br.readLine();

    case 3 :    System.out.println("DISPLAY");

                System.out.println("In Order");
                theTree.inOrderTraverseTree(theTree.root);
                System.out.println("");

                System.out.println("PreOrder");
                theTree.preorderTraverseTree(theTree.root);
                System.out.println("");

                System.out.println("PostOrder");
                theTree.postOrderTraverseTree(theTree.root);
                System.out.println("");




    case 4 :    System.out.println("SEARCH");
                System.out.println("Enter a key to find: ");
                int z = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                //for(int i = 0; i<listLength;i++)
                //{

                    if(theTree.findNode(z)!= null){

    System.out.println("Found it! : " +     theTree.findNode(z) );

                    }
                    else{

                          System.out.println("ERROR: Not found!");

                    }
                        break;




    case 5 :    System.out.println("Bye");
                break;

      default : System.out.println("Try Again");
                break;
}
        }catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }

}while(choice != 5);
}
}
```

Comment: What's the exact question, or the specific problem you're having? It might be a bit of a stretch to expect us to debug the code for you.

Comment: Everytime i run it, it has errors. Errors that i can't fix. can you help me?

Comment: What errors? At a minimum, include full details of the errors in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure we should be doing your homework for you.  What have you done to try debugging it?  This is not a hard algorithm to debug.  A few strategic println's should help you work out what's wrong.

Comment: You have to define Node class first.

Comment: Sorry to not include the details of this i'm just a new comer here. I don't know how to ask questions. The error says " cannot find symbol class Node" i can't fix it :(

Comment: I've already done that but nothing happens Mr. Jaemok Lee.

Comment: Show us your source for the Node class.

Comment: It is indicated at my program.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: No it isn't.  You need to define the class just as you have for BinaryTree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node Class :->

```
package com.shi.tree;

public class Node {
private int key;
private String name;
private Node leftChild,rightChild;
public Node(int key, String name) {
    this.key = key;
    this.name=name;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}
public int getKey() {
    return key;
}
public void setKey(int key) {
    this.key = key;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Node getLeftChild() {
    return leftChild;
}
public void setLeftChild(Node leftChild) {
    this.leftChild = leftChild;
}
public Node getRightChild() {
    return rightChild;
}
public void setRightChild(Node rightChild) {
    this.rightChild = rightChild;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
System.out.println("key :"+this.getKey()+" Name :"+this.getName());
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return super.toString();
}
}
```

BinaryTree Class :->

```
package com.shi.tree;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.shi.tree.Node;
public class BinaryTree {

public static int choice,listLength;



Node root;

public void addNode(int key, String name) {



Node newNode = new Node(key, name);



if (root == null) {

    root = newNode;

} else {




    Node focusNode = root;



    Node parent;

    while (true) {




        parent = focusNode;




        if (key < focusNode.getKey()) {



            focusNode = focusNode.getLeftChild();



            if (focusNode == null) {


                parent.setLeftChild(newNode);
                return;
            }

        } else {

            focusNode = focusNode.getRightChild();


            if (focusNode == null) {



                parent.setRightChild(newNode);
                return;

            }

        }

    }
}

}



public void inOrderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {

if (focusNode != null) {



    inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.getLeftChild());



    System.out.println(focusNode.toString());



    inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.getRightChild());

}

}

public void preorderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {

if (focusNode != null) {

    System.out.println(focusNode);

    preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.getLeftChild());
    preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.getRightChild());

}

}

public void postOrderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {

if (focusNode != null) {

    postOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.getLeftChild());
    postOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.getRightChild());

    System.out.println(focusNode);

}

}

public Node findNode(int key) {



Node focusNode = root;



while (focusNode.getKey() != key) {



    if (key < focusNode.getKey()) {



        focusNode = focusNode.getLeftChild();

    } else {



        focusNode = focusNode.getRightChild();

    }



    if (focusNode == null)
        return null;

}

return focusNode;

}

 public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String x;
int y;

BinaryTree theTree = new BinaryTree();





 theTree.inOrderTraverseTree(theTree.root);









do
{
    try
        {
System.out.println("Choose: ");
System.out.println("[1]Insert ");
System.out.println("[2]Delete ");
System.out.println("[3]Display ");
System.out.println("[4]Search");
System.out.println("[5]Exit");
System.out.println("====================");
choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
switch(choice)
{
case 1 :    System.out.println("INSERT");
            System.out.println("Enter a key: ");
            y = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());


            System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
            x = br.readLine();
            theTree.addNode(y,x);
            System.out.println("Tree: " + theTree.findNode(y));
            break;

case 2 :    System.out.println("DELETE");
            System.out.println("Enter the node to remove: ");
            x = br.readLine();

case 3 :    System.out.println("DISPLAY");

            System.out.println("In Order");
            theTree.inOrderTraverseTree(theTree.root);
            System.out.println("");

            System.out.println("PreOrder");
            theTree.preorderTraverseTree(theTree.root);
            System.out.println("");

            System.out.println("PostOrder");
            theTree.postOrderTraverseTree(theTree.root);
            System.out.println("");




case 4 :    System.out.println("SEARCH");
            System.out.println("Enter a key to find: ");
            int z = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            //for(int i = 0; i<listLength;i++)
            //{

                if(theTree.findNode(z)!= null){

System.out.println("Found it! : " +     theTree.findNode(z) );

                }
                else{

                      System.out.println("ERROR: Not found!");

                }
                    break;




case 5 :    System.out.println("Bye");
            break;

  default : System.out.println("Try Again");
            break;
}
    }catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Try again");
    }

}while(choice != 5);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The major issue is that you definitely have not defined `Node` class , at least not from the code you've provided, despite what you may think.

If you put that code into and IDE (Integrated Development Environment) like Eclipse (which I highly recommend you do since you are new to Java and short on time), you'll see it showing a lot of errors because it can't find your definition of `Node`. Use these error message to help you work out what is wrong with your code.

Hint: if your class definition is in the same file `BinaryTree.java`, it begins like this:

```
class Node {
    /* Your code defining the node class */
}
```

You might also want to clean up the formatting of your code, because as it currently stands it is hard to read and this will make it harder for you in the long run to debug and get your code working as needed.

Everyone here wants to make sure you pass your finals, but you have to actually understand what is going on with your code and why it isn't working. There's no shortcut, work through it methodically, check any errors you get with SO or other sites and pass your finals!

Comment: @LordOreo Glad to hear it. As you're new to SO, please mark a answer correct if it solves your problem so everyone knows it has been resolved. Good luck with finals!

Comment: @LordOreo it is worthwhile getting acquainted with SO, it is a invaluable resource. Quick tour [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).